# Setting Component Property to Use After ngOnInit()

Tags: angular, ngoninit

I am very new to angular. So trying to learn while working on an existing code base.

I'm trying to setup a div to display when a message is loaded in a component.

The div will show fine once the correct property is set.

However, I'm setting the component property before it hits the `ngOnInit` method

I'm setting this property publically as there are more than one places to set this message, I've even set it after the routing has been triggered, but the component hits the `ngOnInit` resetting the property.

Is there a way to set this property, without it being global, for a specific component.

I'm assuming there's a "wait" method I'm not aware of after googling this for ages.

Comment: Angular lifecycle hooks can help you, but please share some code, it will be much easier to understand your context.